# Sync Nexus with local directory

Tags: automation, jenkins-pipeline, nexus, offline-caching

Is there a way to export the entire contents of a Nexus repository to a directory?

I need to be able to pass off all of my artifacts to a different team that is not able to use Nexus.

Even better I would love to be able to keep the directory in sync with Nexus as new artifacts are uploaded.

To be clear, the export directory would be read-only.

Comment: What version of NXRM?

Comment: We are currently using Nexus 2 OSS, but will be migrating to Nexus 3 OSS soon.

Comment: I answered but I'd hope "is not able to use Nexus" isn't a limit on security permissions you can put on the server, because I feel like the scenario you propose is almost an export/import scenario.  It's definitely possible to make repositories read only for certain roles/groups in case you didn't know.

Comment: https://github.com/030/n3dr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nexus Repository Manager 2 is based on a file system, so there's no need to export anything from it, you already have the files you need.  They should be available in your data directory and storage subfolder by repository (e.g. sonatype-work/nexus/storage).  Setting up security for it would depend on your OS but in my mind it would be almost as easy to have another NXRM instance for them to access things, because unless they're accessing the base files, you'll need to store them somewhere anyway.

Nexus Repository Manager 3 is based on a blobstore system so would not be able to do this.  There is a Professional/PRO feature export being developed currently (details [here](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-11468)).  Tangentially, Import for Raw and Maven is available [as of 3.23](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Repository+Import).